# Joinfaces support JSF Primefaces 10

Tags: jsf, primefaces, joinfaces

When **Joinfaces** is planning to support **JSF Primefaces 10**?

Comment: I would ask this on the JoinFaces GitHub issues here: https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PR Submitted for JoinFaces to support PF10.  PF10 will be officially released at the end of Feb so expect it then.

See: https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/pull/867